# Substring on MySQL query

Tags: mysql, database

I have two table that correlate each other. The problem come when I want to make query that shows all `departement_name` on each requestor, but `departement` on `tbl_request` are more than one and separated with comma.

tbl_request:

[image]

tbl_departement:

[image]

Is it possible to make just like this ? And if it isn't, what is the best way at least the closest way to do it.

```
request_id    sow    request_type   date   requestor   departement
==================================================================
11          qwer       jk      2019-07-06  Lutfi       DevOps,Business Dev
12          adga       gadga   2019-07-06  sfags       RnD,DevOps
```

So far, I've do nothing with substring. I'm just playing around with usual query.

```
SELECT
    tbl_request.request_id AS request_id,
    tbl_request.sow AS sow,
    tbl_request.request_type AS request_type,
    tbl_request.date AS date,
    tbl_request.requestor AS requestor,
    tbl_departement.departement_name AS departement_name
FROM
    `tbl_request`
LEFT JOIN 
    tbl_departement ON tbl_request.departement = tbl_departement.departement_id
```

Comment: You should normalize your tables

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Join the 2 tables and group by request. Then use [`group_concat()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat):

```
select 
  r.request_id, r.sow, r.request_type, r.date, r.requestor,
  group_concat(d.department_name) departement
from tbl_request r inner join tbl_departement d
on concat('%,', r.department, ',%') like concat('%,', d.department_id, ',%')
group by r.request_id, r.sow, r.request_type, r.date, r.requestor, r.department
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/oUD9LH8tbQsmata6fruPey/1).
Results:

```
| request_id | sow  | request_type | date       | requestor  | departement         |
| ---------- | ---- | ------------ | ---------- | ---------- | ------------------- |
| 12         | qwer | jk           | 2019-07-06 | Lufti Aldi | Business Dev,DevOps |
| 13         | adga | gadga        | 2019-07-13 | sfags      | RnD,DevOps          |
```

Comment: Great! i don't even think there is group_concat() before. Thanks man! @forpas